# how to set Gitlab project default issues template using the API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

### Background

I am enforcing an issue template so I can extract the business requirement(one-liner describing the issue for non-technical people) from an issue description

[image: Default Issue Description]

### Problem: Gitlab API doesn't have the description field

[image]
According to Gitlab API documentation, there is nothing about the description field in the projects namespace parameters https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#edit-project

### Question: How can I set a default issue template using the API?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: the API doesn't provide this right now.

From what I understand after reading the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/description_templates.html), issue templates exist as files committed to your git repository (inside the `.gitlab/issue_templates/` folder). Therefore, if an API endpoint to do what you want existed, it would have to create a file in the repository with your template in it, then create a new commit on a given branch and push to the repo.

Comment: I want to set the _default_ template, adding templates to `.gitlab/issue_templates` will only add templates that you can choose from from the new issues page, can you think of anyway to do add the default template programmatically given that I have an access token

Comment: I don't think it's possible because the default issue template feature has been abandoned in recent releases of gitlab (like 9.0). See this discussion: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/default-issue-description/6622

Comment: All the screenshots in the question are taken on gitlab.com, which is always up to date, the feature is still there...

Comment: Looking here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18656#note_13262559 in the issue that introduced the description templates, they suggest removing the default templates defined via the web interface. I don't see any changelog entries reflecting that change but that feature is no longer available (don't know if it actually ever was) on my self-hosted gitlab CE instance.

Comment: ok thanks @Jawad, I added a template in the issue_templates, that'll work for now...